# How can I find particular file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I need to find test.xml in IntelliJ IDEA. How can I do that? Keyboard shortcut if any?

Answer (score 113):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> in older versions) leads to the file open dialog (on mac).

You can use `*` chars as wildcards.  If there is more than 1 file with the name, you will see the directory of the file for each entry to help you make the choice.

Comment: hint for future readers: `cmd+shift+o` opened the file open dialog for me

Comment: If its a class file then `cmd+o` would suffice

Comment: And now on Windows it appears to be `ctrl+shift+T`

Answer (score 81):

In Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

or

`Navigate > File...`

Comment: works also in Ubuntu

Comment: works in IntelliJ 2022.1.3, Windows 10

Answer (score 29):

My IntelliJ version is,

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
```

For me, `cmd+shift+n` doesn't work.
But,

```
command + shift + o
```

works perfectly for me.

The above shortcut will give you the dialog box to search a file.

For more help,

On the main menu, point to **Navigate**, and then choose Class, File, or Symbol respectively, or use the following shortcuts:

**Class:** ⌘O

**File (directory):** ⇧⌘O

**Symbol:** ⌥⌘O

Source : JetBrains.com

Comment: Works in IntelliJ 2023.1 on MacOs Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 27):

Just hit quickly **Shift Shift** in a row to reveal a pop-up window to search for everything. You can then start typing to search for files. It's a fuzzy finder, so to match e.g. **S**ome**Cl**ass**W**ithA**L**ong**Na**me.java you can just type: **sclwlna** (or other letters combination, which has the same order of occurance in the target file name).

Comment: This is way more convenient!

Comment: much cooler than ctrl+shift+esc+yourphonenumber+howmuchis34+197?

Comment: Neat! Wonder what this "command" is called? I am trying to find it in the keymap...

Comment: yes this is indeed most convienient, double-shift see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 13):

Well, this is very frequently asked a question by users who switch OS. I recently switched from Windows to MAC.

To open file shortcuts go as follows

Windows : `ctrl+shift+n`
MAC : `command + shift + o`

Answer (score 1):

```
command + E
```

It Will Open Recent Files

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ 2023, MacOS:

1. `CMD + Shift + O` (Search Symbols) Still works.
2. Or you may may setup a shortcut for Search Everywhere
   (I found `Ctrl + Shift + CMD + F` to be comfortable and non-conflicting. Screenshot below.)

[image]